# Live-stream video from one android phone to another android phone over WiFi

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I want to write 2 apps:

1: Master app to control the robot(from the handheld phone) which want to control the slave app and receive the stream.

2: Slave app which will run on the **robot-strapped** phone, controlling the motors/actuators/streaming to master app.

Unfortunately I can not use third party apps. I need to integrate the video stream code into my 2 apps.

What options are there for achieving this? Also is it very hard to do because I never worked with video streaming, tough I am doing pretty good in both Java and Android development.

How should I encode/decode the stream, how do I initiate the connection, will I need to work with UDP instead of TCP/IP? I really don't know where to start, with no sample code anywhere. I am pretty sure this can be achieved. I just can't find anything useful to get me started in the right direction.

I stumbled across spydroid but it is using VLC on a desktop so its no good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like you want and can help you, Let me know some issue about your request Hadi:

1-You indeed want to control a robot with native application on your smart phone?

2-You have a phone on a robot the phone receive your command from master application and control  motors/actuators/streaming ..yes?

3-Whats streaming in this application? do you have Camera on your robot and want to receive Camera view on your master application?

4-Why you dont use some board like Raspberyy Pi for control your robot? you can send command to RasPi over Wifi and Control Please answer some question: 1-you indeed want to control motors/actuators/streaming by the 16 pins exist on that, and can use a camera on RasPi, and stream receive frame to your master application

About:

> Slave app which will run on the robot-strapped phone, controlling the motors/actuators/streaming to master app.
>   How do you want access motor with a smartphone?!!! motor or actuators want get data from standard output that a smartphone dont have that!!!

About:

> Unfortunately i can not use third party apps. I need to integrate the video stream code into my 2 apps.

I think you dont need third application!!! Its done with 2 application completely.

About:

> How should I encode/decode the stream, how do I initiate the connection, will I need to work with UDP instead of TCP/IP? I really don't know where to start, with no sample code anywhere. I am pretty sure this can be achieved. I just can't find anything useful to get me started in the right direction.

I say that you dont need to write full streaming server for a streaming application, some application like **ffmpeg** could stream video very simple and stable,it run in **Linux** and **Windows**.